# Python packages are installing into python3.5 folder rather than python3.6 folder

Tags: python, version, anaconda, jupyter

I've just created a new pythong 3.6 environment using the following instructions:

```
conda create -n py36-test python=3.6
source activate py36-test
python -m ipykernel install --name py36-test
source deactivate
```

To confirm that is the correct format and has installed properly:

```
3.6.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 23 2017, 23:01:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]
```

Now, the kernel does show up and I'm now trying to install packages to this kernel.

Using `pip3 install numpy`, it is installing but it installs into the python3.5 folder rather than python3.6.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Looking online, I haven't found any good resources for how to go about doing this.

Comment: Sometimes `pip3.6` is installed, which only installs to 3.6, correct me if I'm wrong :)

So try `pip3.6` install numpy.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to activate your kernel's env using:

```
source activate kernel-name
```

Now, within that kernel you will be able to install packages using `pip`